# How to automatically add a new instance of a class to an array/vector?

Tags: c++

I am making a simple text based game, but it would be very handy to be able to keep track of all the characters I've made. Im wondering if there is a way to add each new instance of a character to a static array/vector kept within the class. I am not a super experience programmer, but I am pretty sure that the static keyword means its kept over all class but with only 1 instance. So in essence, I would want to be able to call Character::getCharacters() or something like it and it would return all instantiated characters. Alternatively, I could possibly make another class with just that function maybe, but I can't see how and it doesnt sound overly nice.

I've tried make a static vector of made characters, and then on instantiation I call `madeCharacters.push_back(this)`. Unfortunately, this didn't work.

It doesn't give a proper error that I can refer to, instead there is a linker problem; "g++  -o "Trails of Cold Steel Simulator.exe"  ./AoE.o ./Armour.o ./Arts.o ./Character.o ./Crafts.o ./Dice.o ./Enemy.o ./Equipment.o ./Map.o ./MasterQuartz.o ./Quartz.o ./Shoes.o ./Tachi.o ./Weapon.o ./convertPositions.o ./main.o
./main.o:main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZN9Character14madeCharactersE[.refptr._ZN9Character14madeCharactersE]+0x0): undefined reference to `Character::madeCharacters'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:46: Trails of Cold Steel Simulator.exe] Error 1"

For reference, a character is a 'super/parent class' (Im sorry I dont know the word here) of more specific types of characters.

Making the vector not static actually did work though, but then each vector would only hold 1 character, itself.

So what did work;

```
std::vector<Character*> madeCharacters;
```

and

```
Character(Stats const& s, const std::string & n, Position p):baseStats(s), totalStats(s), name(n), currentPosition(p) {madeCharacters.push_back(this);}
```

What didn't work;

```
static std::vector<Character*> madeCharacters;
```

and

```
Character(Stats const& s, const std::string & n, Position p):baseStats(s), totalStats(s), name(n), currentPosition(p) {madeCharacters.push_back(this);}
```

It does compile with the second, not working version, when I take out the creation of any new types of characters, `new xxx()`, but thats not very handy.

Im sure theres something I'm missing here, other game devs have to do something similiar, it's the only way that I can get AoE to work; by going through a list of characters, checking their position and comparing to the AoE positions.

Sorry if this isn't enough information, the jist is that I want to add an object to a vector of that same type of objects when the object is made, in such a way that I can reference a vector of all of that type of object.

Comment: The static vector solution seems a good idea to me. Why it didn't work? What is the error you get in that case?

Comment: `Unfortunately, this didn't work` Create a [mcve]

Comment: @Valentino Ive tried my best to update the question :) Thanks for the comments.

Comment: My secret decoder ring tells me that `madeCharacters` is a class member. If so, then in addition to declaring it as a `static` class member, it is also necessary to define it, in some translation unit, otherwise you get the cited link error. This has nothing to do, whatsoever with a vector being "that same type of object", or anything like that, but a basic C++ concept of a static class member.

Comment: Not enough code. The *individual statements* you posted look fine. But why it didn't work depends *where and how you used those statements*.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yep, you were dead on, I even know of that concept, it was just slightly different to what I'm used to. Sometimes things just slip the mind. Thank you very much. 

For reference, what I did was add to the Character source file (Character.cpp), `std::vector<Character*> Character::madeCharacters;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. In all constructors of the class, add the instance to a container in static storage.
2. Make the constructors of the class private, and write a factory function which creates the object using a private constructor, and adds the object into a container. This approach can be implemented using a non-static container.

Your post mentions attempting 1. without success. The approach is viable - you made a mistake, <strike>but your description is not sufficient for us to be able to tell what that mistake is.</strike> Given the new information, it appears that you've failed to define the static vector.

---

There is a question of how to deal with destruction of the object. Presumably the object would have to be removed from the container. This is one of few cases where a linked list may be a solution. If you store iterator to the list element within the object itself, then the object can remove itself from the list upon destruction.